# Interface definition is a like a type definition

Tags: c#, .net

While reading about interfaces in , I came across this statement that, to CLR an interface definition is just like a type definition i.e. the CLR will define an internal data structure for the interface type object, and reflection can be used to query features of interface type.

Can anyone please clarify the statement

P.S or rather I want to know what does features mean here.

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you need clarification on - the statement seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: reflection can be used to query features of the Value types also.. than why does CLR treat's interfaces as types

Comment: For interface types, _features_ pretty much means the list of functions.

Comment: we can get the list of functions for the value types also. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, indeed. If your concern is with the _just like_ part of the phrase you quote(?) then I agree, interfaces are not _just like_ type definitions, they _are_ type definitions - interface type definitions to be exact.